# Gtk3 ProgressBar(): unable to receive events in Python

Tags: python, gtk3

I'm trying to migrate an audio player, written in python, to GTK3+.  In GTK2 I used progress_bar.add_event(...pointer_motion_notify|button_press) (full code below), and set a signal handler for button_press and pointer_motion_notify.  In GTK3, it appears that ProgressBar() does not emit these signals.

I have implemented a workaround using Overlay() and DrawingArea() which allows the DrawingArea to emit the signals, but should'nt need to...
Is this a bug? or am I doing it wrong?

Code:

```
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk","3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GObject

class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(title='ProgressBar Event Test')
        self.progressbar = Gtk.ProgressBar()
        self.add(self.progressbar)
        self.progressbar.set_events(Gdk.EventMask.BUTTON_PRESS_MASK
                                  | Gdk.EventMask.POINTER_MOTION_MASK)
        self.progressbar.connect("button-press-event", self.on_event, 'button-press')
        self.progressbar.connect("motion-notify-event", self.on_event, 'motion-notify')
        self.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
        self.current_progress = 0.0
        GObject.timeout_add(200,self.update_progress)
        self.show_all()

    def on_event(self, widget, event, data=None):
        print "on_event called for %s signal"%data
        return False

    def update_progress(self):
        self.progressbar.set_fraction(self.current_progress)
        self.current_progress += 0.01
        return self.current_progress <= 1   # False cancels timeout

def main():
    w = MainWindow()
    Gtk.main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 4):

Its probably better to use an eventbox - you add the widget to the eventbox and connect to the eventbox signals themselves.

Thus:

```
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk","3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GObject

class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(title='ProgressBar Event Test')
        eventbox = Gtk.EventBox()
        self.progressbar = Gtk.ProgressBar()
        eventbox.add(self.progressbar)
        self.add(eventbox)
        eventbox.set_events(Gdk.EventMask.BUTTON_PRESS_MASK
                                  | Gdk.EventMask.POINTER_MOTION_MASK)
        eventbox.connect("button-press-event", self.on_event, 'button-press')
        eventbox.connect("motion-notify-event", self.on_event, 'motion-notify')
        self.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
        self.current_progress = 0.0
        GObject.timeout_add(200,self.update_progress)
        self.show_all()

    def on_event(self, widget, event, data=None):
        print "on_event called for %s signal"%data
        return False

    def update_progress(self):
        self.progressbar.set_fraction(self.current_progress)
        self.current_progress += 0.01
        return self.current_progress <= 1   # False cancels timeout

def main():
    w = MainWindow()
    Gtk.main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

More info about the Gtk.Eventbox can be found [here](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/EventBox.html#Gtk.EventBox).

Comment: Thankyou - yes, that does seem a better solution (and probably what EventBox was designed for :-)

Comment: @simonltwick - thanks.  remember on any stackexchange site, dont forget to click the tick button next to any answer you like and wish to accept.  When you have enough rep points click the up or down buttons to say if you are happy/unhappy with any answer.